# How can I prevent a moveend event when adjusting map position in the moveend event handler?

Tags: leaflet

Consider this [example](https://yafred.github.io/leaflet-tests/20161205-adjust-map-on-moveend/).

If the center circle contains a marker when the map finishes moving, then I pan the map so that the marker position is the center of the map.

```
function mapMoveEnd(e) {
    map.off('moveend', mapMoveEnd);
    map.panTo(somewhere); 
    map.on('moveend', mapMoveEnd);
}

map.on('moveend', mapMoveEnd);
```

Although the map.off('moveend') is called before panning, the event handler is called.

Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong ?

EDIT: the comments below helped me find that this is due to panTo() being animated.

Comment: Since js is asynchronous panTo might be called before .off finishes executing Try to have a timeout on panTo

Comment: @AlexParij I would have thought the exact reverse for the same asynchronicity reason: `.on` is executed before `.panTo` finishes, therefore the `"moveend"` listener is already re-attached?

Comment: Thanks for putting me on the right track. @ghybs is right, panTo() ends later (animation: false solves my pb but does not look that nice)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to set a timeout longer than the animation

```
function mapMoveEnd(e) {
    map.off('moveend', mapMoveEnd);
    map.panTo(somewhere, { duration: .25 }); // seconds
    setTimeout(function(){ map.on('moveend', mapMoveEnd); }, 300); // milliseconds
}

map.on('moveend', mapMoveEnd);
```